# update the canvas scene when reaching it's width

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

this is a general question in building a game let's say i am building a game that it is not build under one and only scene but multiple continuous scenes. what is the best way to switch between those scene when the player reach the width of the canvas

**pseudo code**

```
 var scene= 0;
function DrawScene(scene){
   if(player.width >= CanvasWidth){
       player.x= 0;
       Scene.draw(scene);
       scene++;
   }
}

function UpdateWorld(){
  DrawScene(scene);
}
```

this is just a pseudo code of how i thought about it i don't know how this is made in real life game can anyone give me a hint or show me some link that can describe this ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to handle scene switching in a quite general case would be to handle some objects, let's call them switchers, that may have a visual or not ( => it's an invisible door or not), and which will switch scene when the hero overlaps them.
You'll soon want to add conditions to the switch (the hero has this key, is equipped with this weapon, ...).
And the switch should happen only if there's only 'enough' overlap, which could mean, say, that more than 50% of the bounding box of the hero is on top of the door.

For the pseudo-code, there are may ways to do a game loop, but at some point you'll have to do :

```
for each switch in switches {
   if ( overlap( hero, switch ) && switch.canSwitch(hero) ) scene = switch.scene ;
}
```

i did a very small demo to demonstrate.
It is using my all-purpose fiddle as a base, so there's a bit of mess here :-)  : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/bC5JL/

use arrow keys and you will switch between two 'scenes' when overlapping the doors.

Comment: wow nice demonstration thank u for your answer i really appreciate it